# load favicon.ico from referenced project does not work (_host.cshtml)

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-pages

load favicon.ico from referenced project does not work (_host.cshtml)

loading of scripts and css files of referenced projects works, but not for the favicon. it's located in the wwwroot of referenced project.

neither work

```
<image href="_content/Common.Server.UI/favicon.ico" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
<link href="_content/Common.Server.UI/favicon.ico" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thw browser says 404 for the favicon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rel` "Specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document". The relationship attribute should be "icon" not stylesheet which is used for .css files.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon.png">
```

or type ico for .ico files ect.

Comment: interesting. which rel should be used for scripts then? also stylesheet? i guess script but I dont know.

Comment: @CleanCoder you don't use `rel` for scripts. Scripts are referenced using the `script` element. The `rel` attribute is not valid on a `script` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

Comment: right, i misslooked that. there is in fact no rel attribute on script which makes my question pointless.